# Custom Retrofit ErrorHandler gives UndeclaredThrowableException

Tags: android, retrofit

Based on this post [How should I handle "No internet connection" with Retrofit on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20786593/how-should-i-handle-no-internet-connection-with-retrofit-on-android)

I made a custom `ErrorHandler`

```
private static class CustomErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {

    @Override
    public Throwable handleError(RetrofitError error) {
        if (error.isNetworkError()) {
            return new MyNetworkError();
        }

        return error.getCause();
    }
}
```

And now my application crashes and I get this:

```
java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
```

Is there some configuration needed for the adapter? Using `Retrofit 1.6.0` with `OkHttp 2.0.0`

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are returning a checked exception you need to declare it on the interface.

```
interface MyService {
  Foo doFoo() throws MyNetworkError;
}
```