# Retrofit : Custom ErrorHandler, UndeclaredThrowableException

Tags: android, retrofit

I'm using 'Retrofit' for http transferation.

And I made a custom `ErrorHandler` like below code.

```
public class CustomErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {

    @Override
    public Throwable handleError( RetrofitError cause ) {

        if ( RetrofitError.Kind.NETWORK == cause.getKind() ) {

            Throwable throwable = cause.getCause();

            if ( throwable instanceof SocketTimeoutException )
                return throwable;
            else if ( throwable instanceof ConnectException )
                return throwable;
        }

        return cause;
    }

}
```

When I try debugging, `throwable` is instance of `SocketTimeoutException` or `ConnectException` in the `CustomErrorHandler.handleError()`.

But, below fucntion throws `UndeclaredThrowableException`.

```
private SignOutSuccessResponse trySignOut( String email, String userToken ) throws Exception {

    RestAdapter.Builder builder = new RestAdapter.Builder();
    builder.setEndpoint( ServerInfo.END_POINT_API );
    builder.setErrorHandler( new CustomErrorHandler() );

    if ( BuildConfig.DEBUG )
        builder.setLogLevel( RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL );

    API sessionAPI = builder.build().create( API.class );
    return sessionAPI.signOut( email, userToken );
}
```

How can I resolve this problem not [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24616267/4184868)?

I'm using

- Android studio
- Retrofit 1.7.1
- OkHttp 2.0.0

Please help me ㅠㅠ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `SocketTimeException` and `ConnectException` are checked exception as you probably already know.  If you don't want to declare your interface with a checked exception like prescribed in the link you posted then you'll need to wrap both exception into an unchecked exception before returning them.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that `SocketTimeException` and `ConnectException` are 'checked exception'. Thank you!