# Error handling in synchronous call by Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit

I'm trying to figure out the right way to do error handling in Retrofit synchronous calls. I know for asynchronous calls, Retrofit has a callback for failure case. But how should I handle error for synchronous call? My guess is wrapping the call with a try block and handle RetrofitError exception in catch block.

Comment: Why do you want to use synchronous call in Retrofit? Http requests should be sent asynchronously in Android.

Comment: @piotr.wittchen sometimes you're already in a thread, then it makes perfectly good sense to use a synchronous call

Comment: Just adding to that, I think its also needed when you are trying to refresh a token in background after receiving 401 from the sever.

Comment: If you're using Android Priority Job Queue (Job Manager) then you use synchronous calls in the job, it has its uses, I personally don't want to have network calls in the ui classes (Activities)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your guess seems correct, using synchronous calls Retrofit is made to throw a [RetrofitError](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/b9fe6f99398843d84cb967cea29a53996019e4ba/retrofit/src/main/java/retrofit/RetrofitError.java) representing the error: [Reference](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/b9fe6f99398843d84cb967cea29a53996019e4ba/retrofit/src/main/java/retrofit/RestAdapter.java#L188). Note that the  `throw IllegalStateException` in `handleError` shouldn't happen in the case of a synchronous call.

**Edit:** It appears Retrofit is slowly moving on to the 2.0 release, if you plan on using Retrofit 2.0, I recommend reading the documentations to see how it is done in the new version.

**Edit pt2:** Retrofit has moved to 2.0 release and now if you want to handle errors you no longer have to catch RetrofitErrors but IOException.
You can directly have a look at the implementation of execute()

```
/**
 * Synchronously send the request and return its response.
 *
 * @throws IOException if a problem occurred talking to the server.
 * @throws RuntimeException (and subclasses) if an unexpected error occurs creating the request
 * or decoding the response.
 */
Response<T> execute() throws IOException;
```

Other references: [1](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1095)

Answer (score 4):

It's hard to find this. Nobody really talks about the error handling on synchronous calls. But I found something. I'm not entirely sure if the next line should be added (it should definitely be added for custom errors, but this is not the case) I found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24616267/2767703)

```
Foo doFoo() throws RetroFitError;
```

The synchronous call should be happening inside a try catch clause like this:

```
try{
    doFoo();
}catch(RetroFitError e){

}
```

Found [here](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/423)

Comment: Hi Kevin, thanks for your answer. Based on the source https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/retrofit/src/main/java/retrofit/RestAdapter.java#L182 and https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/retrofit/src/main/java/retrofit/ErrorHandler.java there's already a default handler which throws RetrofitError. So if we don't need to handle custom error, we don't have to throws the RetrofitError specifically.

Comment: @feiqu Ohh okay. Then you can leave that away. The try catch method will be your error handler then ;)