# How to handle different types of exceptions and errors in retrofit 2.0.1

Tags: android, rest, httpresponse, retrofit2

I am using Retrofit 2.0.1. I want to handle all types of network errors and exceptions (like no network connection ,timeout error,server not found etc.) I have found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20786593/how-should-i-handle-no-internet-connection-with-retrofit-on-android/21055979#21055979). But some of the methods were deprecated in v1.8.0. How can I do that in 2.0.1?

Answer (score 8):

If you need centeralize error handler take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35031601/1462770) thread But if you just need a simple error handler you can do:

```
 @Override
 public void onFailure(Throwable throwable) {
    if (throwable instanceof HttpException) {
       // We had non-2XX http error
    }
    if (throwable instanceof IOException) {
       // A network or conversion error happened
    }

    // We don't know what happened. We need to simply convert to an unknown error
    // ...
  }
```

Comment: thanks for reply @Amir, I see you link. But when net connection issues are arrive then enter into onFailure and return UnKnownHostException. i want exact particular reason of issues to the user through message?It can be solve by this?

Comment: It's depends what kinds of error you want to handle. for example in above code you can detect  which type of  network disconnect (Wifi | mobile) or in HttpException you can parse 500,400,401,404,....

Comment: Hi Amir, i want to give you test case ,then you can understand. when my network disable and hit the api that enter failure block and give UnKnownHostException that not HttpException .So, in that time it not return any code .So how to handle it?

Comment: @Suman server doesn't return any status code? retrofit  response.code() usually return proper code take a look at that may fix your issue.

Comment: Thanks @Amir for your Support, i can solve it .UnknownHoStException  not HttpError .Need to Handle Like if (throwable instanceof UnknownHostException) {}.

Answer (score 1):

Connection status should be checked anyway and has nothing to do with RetroFit, look up `ConnectivityManager`.

(a quicky solution is something ***like*** this, modify to your needs):

```
public boolean isConnected()
{
  ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
  NetworkInfo info = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

  return (info != null && info.isConnected());
}
```

*EDIT:*
Consider this - `ConnectivityManager` let's you know you have an interface for outgoing data, if you want to know if you actually have an outside link, I would suggest to ping you server (or any other known domian that would respond), if the ping is good, you have a line, for `Timeouts` and `serverNotFound` - use the http codes you get back in onFailure() for an api request (e.g. 404, 400, 200, etc.).

**The Why**

A ping is just a single udp packet that let's you know the server is there and alive, so a scenario where a ping works, but an http request will return `Bad Request` is very possible, and can be handled easily, the logic is up to you.

For the other stuff - all the info you need to implement the handling you want can be found in the callbacks.

this example uses `ResponseBody`, you can get the delivery info from the header:

```
@Override
public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, retrofit2.Response<ResponseBody> rawResponse)
{
  try
  {
   String response = rawResponse.headers().toString();
   //now print this...
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Timeouts and serverNotFound can be handeled through the onFailure callback (this is the skeleton, implement what you need inside it, read up about it):

```
@Override
public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable throwable)
{
 //use throwable.get.... to know what happened
 throwable.printStackTrace();
}
```

Hope this helps in any way

Comment: thanks for reply, ConnectivityManager only check wifi enable or not and data enable or not , After checking this and hit api the but data is  not available in that case its goes to OnFailure block .In that case i want to handle connectin error and server error..there are any way to handle this? i want to show all error and issues user through message

Comment: edited the answer, take a look, keep in mind that you have to catch and understand the response yourself.