# Where is the best place to check for internet connection in MVVM?

Tags: android, mvvm

I have an `apiClass` which makes all the network calls
and I was thinking my options are these:

1. do the check inside the `activity`/`fragment`
2. do the check inside the `apiClient` class

I'm sure there is a better alternative.

EDIT

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22595825/6505084) answer suggests my second option. Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 2):

You can add method for internet connection anywhere but as per my understanding,for code/method  method reuse you can create Util class or You can add it into the Application class.
You can also refer below method.

```
public static boolean getConnectionStatus(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager mConnectivityManager;
    NetworkInfo mNetworkInfoMobile, mNetworkInfoWifi;

    mConnectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    mNetworkInfoMobile = mConnectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
    mNetworkInfoWifi = mConnectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
    try {
        if (mNetworkInfoMobile.isConnected()) {
            App.connectivityStatus = 1;

            return true;
        }
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        // exception.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (mNetworkInfoWifi.isConnected()) {
        App.connectivityStatus = 1;

        return true;
    } else {
        App.connectivityStatus = 0;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: mvvm design pattern you can follow below links         https://barta.me/android-mvvm-pattern/                            https://medium.com/upday-devs/android-architecture-patterns-part-3-model-view-viewmodel-e7eeee76b73b

Comment: This should in a a service layer because the ViewModel shouldn't care whether or not you're connected other than showing an icon. Nor should it be a static method.

Comment: The question is not where to define the method. But the question is where to use it.

Answer (score 1):

create class connectivity manager in livedata

```
class Connectivity_check_internet(val context: Context) : LiveData<Boolean>() {
    val connectivityManager = context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
    var Connnectserver: Boolean? = false
    val reciveconnctivitymanager = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(p0: Context?, p1: Intent?) {
            Connnectserver=false
            UnpdateConnection()
            postValue(Connnectserver)
        }
    }
    init {
        UnpdateConnection()
    }

    fun UnpdateConnection(){
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            val capabilities = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(connectivityManager.activeNetwork)
            capabilities?.run {
                Connnectserver=capabilities!!.hasTransport(TRANSPORT_CELLULAR) || capabilities.hasTransport(TRANSPORT_WIFI)
            }
        } else {
            try {
                val activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.activeNetworkInfo
                Connnectserver = activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected
            } catch (e: Exception) {
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onActive() {
        super.onActive()
        context.registerReceiver(
            reciveconnctivitymanager,
            IntentFilter("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE")
        )
    }

    override fun onInactive() {
        super.onInactive()
        context.unregisterReceiver(reciveconnctivitymanager)
    }
}
```

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
val Connectivity_internet by lazy {
Connectivity_check_internet(this)
}

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    Connectivity_internet.observe(this,{
        Log.e("TAG", "onCreate: "+it )
    })

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I think we should avoid using `Context` in `ViewModel` and data layer as much as possible. Therefore, the best place to check the Internet is where we have access to the `Context`, for example, in `Activity` or `Fragment`.