# How to make test code for HTTP 204 No Content in Android, Rx

Tags: android, junit, retrofit, rx-java, http-status-code-204

I am developing an android app using Kotlin, RxJava, and Retrofit.

I am sending a request to delete a resource.

HTTP - DELETE

And the response is 204 No Content.
My retrofit code is below:

```
@DELETE("res/{resId}")
fun deleteJob(@Path("resId") resId: String): Observable<Unit>
```

In this case I don't know how to define the return type.
So I defined "Observable".
Because there are no response body.
Response code is 204.

And below is my presenter code:

```
override fun deleteRes(resId: String) {
    restService.deleteRes(resId)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe({
                // here is not called
            }, {
                // Always here is called, because the response is 204.
                if (it is NoContentException) { // I defined new exception.
                    view.removeRes(resId)
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "deleteRes - failed: ${it.message}")
                }
            })
}
```

I want to test this Presenter function.

Below is my test code:

```
@Test
fun deleteResTest() {
    val deleteResId = "delete_res_id"

    Mockito.`when`(mockRestService.deleteRes(deleteResId)).thenReturn(Observable.just(Unit))
    mockRestService.deleteRes(deleteResId)
        .toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER)
        .subscribe(TestSubscriber.create<Unit>())

    mJobsPresenter.deleteRes(deleteResId)

    Mockito.verify(mockView).removeRes(deleteResId)
}
```

But when I run this test code, it's failed like this:

```
Wanted but not invoked:
view.removeRes("delete_res_id");
-> at com.RessPresenterTest.deleteResTest(ResPresenterTest.kt:95)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

Wanted but not invoked:
view.removeRes("delete_res_id");
-> at com.RessPresenterTest.deleteResTest(ResPresenterTest.kt:95)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

at com.RessPresenterTest.deleteResTest(ResPresenterTest.kt:95)
```

Somebody help me, please?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45658276/how-to-catch-the-exception-in-retrofit-android

Comment: I am asking about how to write the test code..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to use `Completable` instead of `Observable` for "204 no content" responses, because these responses have not any content and we just need the `onComplete` and `onError` methods. so you can create a `Completable` and call `onComplete` method in test.